# Pull "Player" "Stats" from a JSON

Tags: python, json, list, io

I have a very large JSON file that had thousands of simulated basketball games, with stats for every player in every game. I'd like to be able to pull those out to a csv eventually, but right now all I want to do is to be able to get the stats as a string into an array.

The code I have compiles, but doesn't seem to do what I want it to do, the stats = [] I am defining to write the stats into remains empty.

Here is my program so far:

```
import os

#create path for file
path = os.path.dirname('C:\\tmp\\Season3Playoffs.json')
#create list for stats for each player
stat = []
#open file
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), encoding = "UTF-8") as input_file:
        #go through each line of the file
        for line in input_file:
            #if a line has "pid" copy contents to the list stat until "psid" is encountered
            if line in ('"pid"', '"psid"'):
                stat.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
                #print the stat entry
                print(stat)
print("program complete")
```

Here is an example of what a section of the JSON file looks like that I am wanting to save in each element of the list:

```
"value": 64.8,
      "valueNoPot": 72,
      "valueFuzz": 64.8,
      "valueNoPotFuzz": 72,
      "valueWithContract": 64.8,
      "pid": 1,
      "imgURL": "",
      "firstName": "Chris",
      "lastName": "Bosh",
      "diedYear": null,
      "stats": [
        {
          "pid": 1,
          "season": 2015,
          "tid": 27,
          "playoffs": false,
          "gp": 0,
          "gs": 0,
          "min": 0,
          "fg": 0,
          "fga": 0,
          "fgAtRim": 0,
          "fgaAtRim": 0,
          "fgLowPost": 0,
          "fgaLowPost": 0,
          "fgMidRange": 0,
          "fgaMidRange": 0,
          "tp": 0,
          "tpa": 0,
          "ft": 0,
          "fta": 0,
          "pm": 0,
          "orb": 0,
          "drb": 0,
          "trb": 0,
          "ast": 0,
          "tov": 0,
          "stl": 0,
          "blk": 0,
          "ba": 0,
          "pf": 0,
          "pts": 0,
          "per": 0,
          "ewa": 0,
          "yearsWithTeam": 1,
          "psid": 0
        }
      ]
```

From that code I want the text between "pid: x" and "psid:" to be saved in stat[x].

I don't see why it's not writing to the array, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)?

Comment: I'm a beginner and don't know about the module, looking to increase basic python skills as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might work.

```
import json
data = json.loads("""{
    "value": 64.8,
    "valueNoPot": 72,
    "valueFuzz": 64.8,
    "valueNoPotFuzz": 72,
    "valueWithContract": 64.8,
    "pid": 1,
    "imgURL": "",
    "firstName": "Chris",
    "lastName": "Bosh",
    "diedYear": null,
    "stats": [
        {
            "pid": 1,
            "season": 2015,
            "tid": 27,
            "playoffs": false,
            "gp": 0,
            "gs": 0,
            "min": 0,
            "fg": 0,
            "fga": 0,
            "fgAtRim": 0,
            "fgaAtRim": 0,
            "fgLowPost": 0,
            "fgaLowPost": 0,
            "fgMidRange": 0,
            "fgaMidRange": 0,
            "tp": 0,
            "tpa": 0,
            "ft": 0,
            "fta": 0,
            "pm": 0,
            "orb": 0,
            "drb": 0,
            "trb": 0,
            "ast": 0,
            "tov": 0,
            "stl": 0,
            "blk": 0,
            "ba": 0,
            "pf": 0,
            "pts": 0,
            "per": 0,
            "ewa": 0,
            "yearsWithTeam": 1,
            "psid": 0
        }
    ]
}""")

print(data['stats'])
```